# C++ Qt WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I am trying to WriteProcessMemory using Qt with QtCreator. When i press the button it doesn't write. Here is the code i am using if anyone could help.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <windows.h>

HANDLE hProcess;
int MYBASE;

void Attach() {
    DWORD pid;
    HWND hWindow = FindWindow(NULL, L"Generic Property Editor Thingy");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWindow, &pid);
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, pid);
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Attach();
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (void*)0x4E709C, (void*)(PBYTE)"\xEB", 1, NULL);

}
```

Comment: HANDLE is a typedef used in windows.h. Are you sure you want to use such a platform specific type in Qt?

Comment: You'll need to add `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: i want to use whatever is standard in QT. im not sure because ive only made this for C++

Comment: And why are you using Win32 API functions in Qt? Just curious, because your errors suggest that you didn't include the Win32 API header files.

Comment: what functions should i use in qt?

Comment: @ksming, he is writing to process memory, I don't think he cares about portability.

Comment: yah i want portability thats why im using qt, im not sure what functions qt would use for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you haven't solve this error:

```
mainwindow.cpp(103) : error C3861: 'Attach': identifier not found
```

function names are cases sensitive in C/C++ etc ... So rename your function to "Attach(...)"

Answer (score 2):

You are missing an include to `windows.h`.

This was determined by the error

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'hProcess'
```

as `hProcess` is declared as

`HANDLE hProcess;`

There for, the type before `hProcess` is undefined.

To solve your issue, you must have the following

```
#include <windows.h>
```

Comment: Now im just getting these errors. ' mainwindow.cpp(13) : error C2664: 'FindWindowW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'const char [31]' to 'LPCWSTR'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
mainwindow.cpp(14) : error C2664: 'GetWindowThreadProcessId' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int *' to 'LPDWORD'
        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
mainwindow.cpp(105) : error C3861: 'Attach': identifier not found '

Comment: While it is kind of hard to read the formatting (I suggest modifying your original answer with this message) it looks like your have a unicode vs multibyte problem.

Comment: To change your unicode vs multibyte setting on a VS2010 project, go to Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General and look at "Character Set".